# T-SQL, how to get top three maximum values and if repeats, include them?

Tags: sql, t-sql

As stated in the title, I wish to select the top 3 values, and if the value that is counted repeats, include it too.

```
SELECT b.planID, count(b.planID) AS PopularPlan
FROM dbo.Subscriber as b
GROUP BY B.planID
ORDER BY count(b.planID) DESC;
```

This output returns all of the maximum values, ex:

```
PlanID  PopularPlan
 101    2555
 123    2555
 432    2390
  23    2390
  45    2090
  12    2080
  55    2090
```

If I were to use TOP 3, to choose TOP 3, with the following SQL:

```
SELECT TOP 3 b.planID, count(b.planID) AS PopularPlan
FROM dbo.Subscriber as b
GROUP BY B.planID
ORDER BY count(b.planID) DESC;
```

It would return the following:

```
PlanID  PopularPlan
 101    2555
 123    2555
 432    2390
```

The desired output in this situation would be to do what I want is:

```
PlanID  PopularPlan
     101    2555
     123    2555
     432    2390
      23    2390
      45    2090
```

I understand that the TOP 3 limits to only three results, but I cannot seem to figure out an approach how to add if it is repeated.

Furthermore, if I were to include WITH TIES:

```
SELECT TOP 3 WITH TIES b.planID, count(b.planID) AS PopularPlan
FROM dbo.Subscriber as b
GROUP BY B.planID
ORDER BY count(b.planID) DESC;
```

The output in this case is:

```
PlanID  PopularPlan
     101    2555
     123    2555
     432    2390
      23    2390
```

Upon testing, if I choose TOP 5 the 2090 value appears, but I wish to do the same with TOP 3 if possible so that the output is as-is:

```
PlanID  PopularPlan
     101    2555
     123    2555
     432    2390
      23    2390
      45    2090 <- has to have this value too
```

Comment: `where planid in (select top(3) planid from t group by... order by...)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DENSE_RANK() is your friend:

```
WITH cteOriginal AS
(
    SELECT b.planID, count(b.planID) AS PopularPlan
    FROM dbo.Subscriber as b
    GROUP BY B.planID
)
, cteDenseRank AS
(
    SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER( ORDER BY PopularPlan DESC) AS DRank
    FROM cteOriginal
)
SELECT planID, PopularPlan
FROM cteDenseRank
WHERE DRank <= 3
ORDER BY PopularPlan DESC
;
```

Presumably you could merge the two CTEs together, but I am never sure exactly how the OVER functions interact with GROUP BY, so I did it this slightly longer way.

Personally I can say that since ROW_NUMBER(), RANK() and DENSE_RANK() windowing functions came out in T-SQL (2008?) I hardly ever use TOP any more.

Edited - the DENSE_RANK() To show the top results.

Comment: Thank you, never heard about DENSE_RANK(), While running the SQL, the following error has appeared: " The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified. "

Removing the " ORDER BY count(b.planID) DESC" resolved the issue, but current output is completely different and shows incorrect values.

Comment: @Marius Sorry, move your original query's ORDER BY clause to the end of the final SELECT statement (but before the ";").  I will edit my answer too ...  OK, I have corrected it.

Comment: wait ... found another typo.  Should be good now.  OK, the syntax checker accepts it now.

Comment: Correct, there was a typo, I've adjusted before noticing, but even afterwards I'm getting the following error: "Column 'cteDenseRank.planID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

I'm not sure in where exactly we should place GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I have made a change to the last line (ORDER BY) that should fix the most recent error.  But, I cannot really test this because I do not have the tables or original data.

Comment: Yes, the error has been resolved. The current issue is that the data which is received is not the biggest. but receives the smallest data which does not repeat.

Comment: @Marius Yep.  I've made some test data and tables, the problem is that I overlooked the DESC in your original ORDER BY, I have to add that to the DENSE_RANK() also ...  OK I've change the DENSE_RANK() to `OVER( ORDER BY PopularPlan DESC)`  And this does appear to work in my testing.

Comment: Thank you, that has resolved the issue. This was a learning experience. I'm very gratefull! Thank you!